# Exporting tweets splits awkwardly

Tags: r, twitter, web-scraping

Hi: I have a TwitteR script that is grabbing tweets just fine. However, when I convert the results to a data.frame and write out with `write.table()` some tweets are split awkwardly. This will pose problems down the road as I try to analyze these?

I've attached some images from the csv files to try to illustrate the problems.

I see that in quite a few of the rows, there are these weird   symbols, which I think have something to do with character encoding, but the splits are not necessarily occuring at those points. So I don't know what is going.

[Link to output file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sjkiss/sjkiss.github.io/master/files/02-17-20-00.csv)

[image: Splits in the text field]
[image: Splits in the the text field]
[image: This one is really weird; it splits in the text field and then again but over three rows.]

The code is here:

```
options(httr_oauth_cache=T)
Sys.setenv(TZ='EST')


setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token,         
access_token_secret)

#Get #onpoli tweet
onpoli<-searchTwitter('#onpoli+#pcpoldr+#pcpo', resultType='recent', n=1500)

#Turn to data.frames
onpolidf<-twListToDF(onpoli)

#Write out to .csv files
write.table(onpolidf, paste('Tweets/', format(Sys.time(), "%m-%d-%H-%M"), 
'.csv', sep=''), append=T, sep=',', col.names=T)
```

Results of SessionInfo() are here:

```
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.3

Matrix products: default
BLAS:         
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/C/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] twitteR_1.1.9

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] bit_1.1-12     httr_1.2.1     compiler_3.4.1 rjson_0.2.15   R6_2.2.2               
DBI_0.7        tools_3.4.1    curl_2.7      
[9] yaml_2.1.16    bit64_0.9-7    openssl_0.9.6
```

Comment: An image of data is a bit hard to deal with. Do you have an actual (textual) sample of data that you can add to the question? This this truly a problem with `twitteR` code or could it be a locale/encoding issue?

Comment: I added a link to the file.